# How to copy many photo file names with date and time to spreadsheet

Tags: command-line, files

I have numerous motion detector photos (JPGs) I copy to a DVD every day.  I would like to copy the file name, original creation date and time of each of these photos and then extract this information to a spreadsheet to do analysis.

Any help appreciated.  Am a new user to Ubuntu 12.04.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First go to the directory where  all your files are stored and then
use this command at the terminal:

```
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9","$6","$7","$8}' > myfile.csv
```

It will create your excel file with file name `myfile.csv` and the order will be
*fileName createdMonth dayofMonth time*.

Answer (score 1):

#### Exiftool ([libimage-exiftool-perl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libimage-exiftool-perl) [image: Install libimage-exiftool-perl])

With this powerfull comand line tool we can manipulate and extract EXIF information of a high variety of files ([see here](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html) fo all options).

To extract filename and date of all images in a directory in CSV format we may issue

```
exiftool -csv -r -filename -dateTimeOriginal /full/path/to/directory > output.csv
```

or

```
exiftool -T -r -filename -dateTimeOriginal /full/path/to/directory > output.txt
```

for text format. Of course we can also browse for all other EXIF tags available.

[image: Install via the software center]